# Why does an int parameter allow passing a char value, but a char parameter doesn't accept passing an int value?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, char, int

When I declare a Java method, why does a Java int parameter accept a passed char value, but a char parameter doesn't accept a passed int value?

For example:

```
// method which : int parameter
public static void printInt(int input) { 
    System.out.println(input);
}
// method which : char parameter
public static void printChar(char input) {
    System.out.println(input);
}

// main 
System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
printInt('a');      // print 97 [number of ASCII char 'a']
                    // int parameter accept char value
printChar(97);      // compilation error
                    // char parameter NOT accept int value
System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
```

Comment: @khelwood it's because `int` is considered "wider" than `char` due to the range over values it can have.  Note: `float` which is 32-bit is wider than` `long` which is 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Implicit casting`**

Since `int` is big enough to accommodate all possible values for `char`, the automatic cast will be performed - which is called **implicit casting** and hence you don't need to do anything while calling that method with char.

You could use explicit cast:

```
printChar((char)97);
```

**But beware this dangerous unless you are sure what you are trying to achieve.**

Comment: There is a `(char) 1000` http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3E8/index.htm Your first explanation is right, it won't cast an `int` to a `char` implicitly.

Comment: @PeterLawrey and @ khelwood corrected, my mistake

Comment: Note: `float` which is 32-bit is wider than `long` which is 64-bit as it has a wider range. The number of bytes is not the reason.